# How can I write a super annotation for checkstyle exemptions?

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle

I'm new to annotations. What I am trying to do is write one that includes others. I've never needed one before and I'm new to them so this is partially for the learning experience.

I have a checkstyle exemption for some third party code and nobody wants to add the exemption to the Sonar server for me. What I want to do is write a super-annotation that will allow me to be selective with my checkstyle exclusions rather than applying @SupressWarnings("all") which seems dangerous to me. The proposed annotation basically just applies groups of @SupressWarnings("put checkstyle keys here"). First version will just exclude all checkstyle. Next version will add capability to do so by category, subcategory and so on down to closer to leaf exclusions. Could use any advice I can get. Am in the process of reading what ever I can get on annotations right now but also have not used reflection much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SuppressWarnings annotations is very compiler/IDE specific. You cannot make your own annotation entries within it that will magically modify the Java compiler - unless you are willing to do a project-lombok style code generation to change the @SuppressWarnings("your-specific-syntax") to various other @SuppressWarnings. For that you have to interact with the AST. Look at the Lombok source code and read up on Annotation Processing Tool (APT).

Comment: My intention was just to write a simple and safe annotation for shutting up Sonar about the generated code nobody cares about and I can't change anyway. The thing is that every now and then somebody gets the wrong idea from the botched statistics and freaks out. No, they won't change the server config for me.

Comment: Closest to the correct answer. Correct answer is probably, "get a better job".

Answer (score 0):

That is already built in in Checkstyle.
You have to activate and set a specific exlusion string which triggers checkstyle 
to ignore the specified warnings for the next N lines.

Use a custom checkstyle configuration  checks.xml, and add:

```
<module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
    <property name="commentFormat" value="CS\:IGNORE ([\w\|]+) (\d+)"/>
    <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
    <property name="influenceFormat" value="$2"/>
  </module>
```

Now you can ignore specific checks with a comment above the line or method:

Example:

```
// CS:IGNORE Catch|MethodLength 10
public void longMethod() {
  // Method that would cause checkstlye to detetced a length and Catch Exception warning
}
```

Catch|MethodLength : Ignore Warnings for: Catch and MethodLength

10 means: the exclusion rule is valid for the next 10 lines.

Comment: i dont understand, server access? you have to change, or ask the build manager, to setup individual checkstyle configuration, which sinply can be copied from the standard checkstyle config.

Comment: Requests which they have ignored. I have to assume the will continue to ignore them.